# Uploading a file in Angular Ionic app by calling an API

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

It fails to upload the file. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

The `else` part gets called error in API call.

The API is working when tested with Postman.

tab1.page.html

```
<div class="">
  <ion-label floating>Add your profile picture</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="file" name="file" id="file (change)="uploadPicture($event)"></ion-input>
</div>
```

tab1.page.ts

```
uploadPicture(event) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("profile_pic",  event.target.files[0], event.target.files[0].name);
  console.log(formData);

  this.api.uploadPic(formData).then((res) => {
     console.log("uploadPicture API call complete");
     console.log(res);
   }, (err) => {
       console.log("Error in API");
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

api.service.ts

```
async uploadPic(file) {
   console.log("api input Pic "+ file);
   console.log(file);

   return await (this.http.post(environment.endpoint + "/upload", file)).toPromise();
}`
```

Error I am getting is

```
message: "Http failure response for localhost:8000/upload: 0 Unknown Error" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 0 statusText: "Unknown Error" url: "localhost:8000/upload"
```

Comment: What error you are getting please post the error in the question also

Answer (score 0):

Use File Transfer Plugins.

imports

```
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
import { FileTransferObject, FileUploadOptions } from "@ionic-native/file- 
transfer/ngx";
import { File, FileEntry } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
```

constructor..

```
private filePath: FilePath,
private file: File,
private fileTransfer: FileTransferObject,
private fileChooser: FileChooser,
```

code ...

```
 createNew() {
try {
  this.fileChooser.open()
    .then((uri: any) => {
      console.log(uri)
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(filePath => {
        // this.filesPath = filePath;
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath).then(fileInfo => {
          let files = fileInfo as FileEntry;
          files.file(success => {
            console.log(success);
            this.uploadDocs(uri, success.name, success)
          });
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
          var name = uri;
          name = name.substr(-10);
          console.log('name1', name);
          // this.util.getErrorAlert('Error Make sure File is inside Download Folder or In Root Directory');
        });
      }, err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
        var name = uri;
        name = name.substr(-10);
        console.log('name2', name);
        this.uploadDocs(uri, name, uri);
        // this.util.getErrorAlert('Error Make sure File is inside Download Folder or In Root Directory');
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
      this.util.showErrorAlert(e);
    }
    );

} catch (error) {
  console.log('err', error);
  this.util.showErrorAlert(error);
}
```

}

```
 uploadDocs(uri, name, file) {
console.log('fil?', file);
let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: 'file',
  fileName: name,
  mimeType: file.type,
  chunkedMode: true,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
};
// user_id
// url
this.util.showLoader();
this.fileTransfer.upload(uri, environment.url + 'upload_file', options1).then((upload: any) => {
  this.util.stopLoader();
  console.log('uploaded', JSON.parse(upload.response));
  let file = JSON.parse(upload.response);

  }
}, error => {
  this.util.stopLoader();
  this.util.showErrorAlert('Something went Wrong while Upload certificate');
  console.log('error', error);
})
```

}